# $.ajax arbit missing ; before statement

Tags: php, jquery

initially I used

$.get(../../some url);

It was working fine.But I had to change the url to complete url like http://thinkmovie.in/blah/blah. After that i started getting 407 proxy authentication error. Then I used this 
$.ajax with dataype:json

```
$('#imgsearch').click(function(){
    $('#albumd').html("<img src='http://thinkmovie.in/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
    var text = $('input[name=search]').val();
    var cat = $('input[name=cat]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://thinkmovie.in/calls/imagesearch.php",
        data: { text:text,cat:cat },
        chache:true,
        dataType: "jsonp",

    });

});
```

Now the error I m getting is this

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

...margin-top:10px;">sruthi hasan</h2><div id="imagsch" style="float:left;margin-le...
```

I tried to change the datatype to some other format and still getting error. 
Please help me.

Comment: Just fyi, `chache` should be `cache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    dataType: "jsonp",
                     ^---extra comma
```

Comment: what is that a mistake, how would I add extra linkes like cache:true etc, If I dont put a comma

Comment: Then you add the comma at that time. But there's quite a few JS engines that'll treat that dangling comma as an error.